# iOS Watchkit: Is it possible to show static UI in Watch when app is not reachable?

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

Can we show some static UI in the watch when iPhone  is not reachable to AppleWatch?

Suppose I forgot my iPhone at car seat , and when I move from car, Is it possible to shows some static UI in AppleWatch that you forgot your iPhone?

Answer (score 9):

From an Apple evangelist on https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254576?tstart=0

> The end result is that if iPhone is unreachable, the app will not
>   function. There is not a way to currently cache information to keep it
>   alive or seemingly so.

Answer (score 1):

In WatchOS 2, it is now possible to have a WatchKit App that runs on the Watch when the iPhone is not accessible.

*Previous answer:*
It is clear from Apple's public statements and the WatchKit API that third party developers do not need to manage the connectivity between the watch and the phone, and indeed cannot even if they want to.

Given Apple have publicly indicated that Watch app interactions are expected to be measured in seconds, not minutes, and that developers need to assume that their Watch app could be quit at any time (and the associated WatchKit extension) it seems highly likely that there will not be any option to present static content in the event of the phone being unreachable—as the Watch OS will immediately take over the process of interacting with the user.

It seems almost certain that this will change later in 2015, given developers have been told there will be an SDK to develop 'fully native' apps at that time.

Comment: Thanks @duncan-babbage  , I think we can achieve it now on iWatch 2 OS because of now watch-kit is move from iPhone to iWatch. But not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't have to do anything. I noticed on the real Watch, that Apple will present a default "iPhone unavailable" screen in case the iPhone is out of reach. Similarly, Apple will also present a default "flight mode" screen when the Watch is in flight mode :) . See attached screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a special setting to enable this? Seems that this behaviour isn't available in watchOS 2

Answer (score -2):

Technically speaking you could start off the app storyboard scene with static content. if the phone is unreachable, then this scene will be displayed. But as soon as your app, whether programmatically or by user interaction attempts to use anything from the WatchKit Extension, a spinner will appear.

Comment: I thought this was an interesting proposal.  Not sure about the downvotes - does it not work this way in practice?  ie, maybe the storyboard scene isn't even shown if the phone is unreachable.